# ссылка на страницу через select

Tags: javascript, html

Есть на форме выпадающий список. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли не затрагивая `value` сделать ссылку на страницу при выборе селекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы с чем работаете?

Comment: html и javascript

Comment: <option  selected="selected" value="6300">Белава</option> value уже используется для вычисления формул

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте, Лиана. Можно так, то есть тупо смотреть на внутренний текст выбранного option:

```
<select id="list" onchange="Change(this);">
    <option value="Выберите героя">Выберите героя</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(data) {
    debugger;
    if (data.selectedOptions && data.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
        var selectedOption = data.selectedOptions[0];
        if (selectedOption.innerText == 'Чебурашка') {
            window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com');
        } else if (selectedOption.innerText == 'Крокодил Гена') {
            window.location.replace('http://google.com');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Или так. Например, нам не нужен value, мы будем использовать свой атрибут, почему нет:

```
<select id="list" onchange="Change(this);">
    <option value="Выберите героя">Выберите героя</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка" data-link="http://stackoverflow.com">Чебурашка</option>
    <option value="Крокодил Гена" data-link="http://google.com">Крокодил Гена</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(data) {
    debugger;
    if (data.selectedOptions && data.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
        var selectedOption = data.selectedOptions[0];
        var dataLink = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-link');
        if (dataLink) {
            window.location.replace(dataLink);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Только продебажьте код, пожалуйста. Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо,сеичас попробую

Comment: <option value="Чебурашка" data-link="http://stackoverflow.com">Чебурашка</option> второи вариант подошел, так как проще сразу ссылки прописать внутри селектов. Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так

```js
// This should be placed in config file
var locationsMap = {
  1: "http://www.google.com",
  2: "http://www.images.google.com",
  3: "http://www.maps.google.com",
}

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  console.log('Changed', e.target.value);
  const href = locationsMap[e.target.value];
  if (href) window.open(href, '_blank');
  // or: document.location.href = href;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="1">
      Open Google
    </option>
    <option value="2">
      Open Google Images
    </option>
    <option value="3">
      Open Google Maps
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Пример на JSFiddle
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/0mjoomvm/3/)